# Avoid changes on a tracked file

Tags: mercurial

I've files that are automatically created (empty) that I want to be added in my mercurial repo but never modified after the first add/commit.

I tried to use a precommit hook `revert "glob:**.ext"` it works on avoiding commit changes but it also prevent commit adding those files. I need those file to be tracked because I use hg purge sometimes and it delete every untracked/ignored files.

I use TortoiseHg (unfornutately I've no choice).

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: I think it would be best, if you just backup those files, and have a script that copies them over in your project structure, after you do a purge.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this extension called [exclude](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExcludeExtension).

Other options

1. Add a template file. For eg: Add `something.ext.template` to your repository and add `something.ext` to `.hgignore`.
2. Add this to your .hgrc

> > [defaults]
> >
> > commit = -X something.ext

But i think the above might exclude it from the initial commit as well.